# Trying to perform transient frequency response with LTspice or Microcap, TL494 compensation

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, switch-mode-power-supply, signal-processing, compensation

I have tried to do Bode plot of my uncompensated plant by myself in LTspice 17.1, but the result looks strange to me. This topic is a follow-on to [this one.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/655264/tl494-compensation). I have no clue why it comes with 290 degree phase margin because it’s always so close to 180 degrees.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you know the difference between AC and transient analyses?

Comment: Well honestly " I dont" but i think transient analyses is  about circuit behavior when load is connected. We want as fast response as possible. And AC analyses is about injecting signal of various frequency and looking on gain and phase and the reason is to maintain negative feedback. We dont want circuit to oscilate at the output. But i am quite a newbie, sorry for missunderstoods. I dont have a teacher.

Comment: No no, not what you want from it. What SPICE is actually doing. It only knows what you've told it to do. And you can only tell it things it's been programmed to do. The "AC Analysis" option does a DC analysis (`.op`), linearization, and small-signal AC steady-state analysis. A highly nonlinear circuit like this will have a meaningless operating point. You must do a transient simulation, and average over many switching cycles, to get the control system response. Or use a simulator that can do a more advanced analysis mode (periodic steady state?).

Comment: @TimWiliams Sorry I run simulation on "transient frequency response". I have added picture of it. Its new feature in Ltspice 17.1. I have also downloaded microcap 12, its maybe a better option, but i was more familiar with LtSpice. https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice/w/faqs-docs/18464/generate-a-bode-plot-for-an-smps-in-ltspice-17-1

Comment: Aha, so they added something like that. Seems I'm less familiar with LTspice than I thought!

Comment: I have added another graph, Just realize that i am injecting too small signal (25mv) so increased it to 5V at lower frequencies and 1V at highers. Does it looks realistic?

Comment: That looks more reasonable. I don't know that the cutoff and corner frequencies are correct, nor the loop gain. Wait, that's with zero compensation too?

Comment: @TimWilliams He is using the latest version (17.1) which added some features and hopefully fixed some bugs. Good to see that it is for everybody to download now.

Comment: If you want the control-to-output TF of the converter, meaning in your case you run the analysis on an uncompensated design, you have to *physically* open the loop and run the frequency-response analyzer (FRA) from here. Drive the FB pin directly from the sine source to which a dc offset is added. This offset will set the operating point - 200 V/5 A - while the sine wave will ac-modulate the FB input. Place the FRA between the FB and \$V_{out}\$ and you should see the power stage response with a phase logically starting from 0° and approaching -180° for a voltage-mode buck-derived converter.

Comment: @verbalKint  I am playing around with Microcap and Ltspice - added 3 more pictures. Probably i need to place Loop gain probe between Caps and Rload. I have added inejction transformer, injection resistor and AC source to sweep.  I would like to plot those equations                                                                                                        Loop= db(Vout/Vin)
Comp=db(Fb/Vin)
PowerStage=db(Vout/FB)  But i am still getting some nonsense results, proving that i dont know what i am actually doing =). Instead of stability analysis i was using AC analysis whole time.

Comment: Also i need to disable operationg point in dialogue else i am getting error "failed to converge during DC operating point". I think that microcap is doing sweep before PSU even stabilize at 200V, so its start sweeping at the start up. Also i did not have found where i can setup variable amplitude at diferent frequencies to avoid saturation at higher frequencies of op amps.

Comment: @MacIntoshCZ FYI, you can set initial conditions on capacitors, inductors, nodes, etc. In particular, setting the initial output voltage would seem helpful. (You may need settings to disable DC `.op` or enable the use of initial values. Which combination is required varies between simulators.)

Comment: @MacIntoshCZ, the command dB(Vout/Vin) is a for a .AC analysis which is for a linear (non-switching circuit). Your circuit is switching so it won't work. As far as I know, only LTspice has this FRA capability, not Microcap. If you want to simulate your loop response, you must resort to an average model and then ac-sweep the circuit. Or go for a SIMPLIS model. I have a full-bridge ready-made template you can use in open-loop to extract the control-to-output transfer function you want.

Comment: @VerbalKint I have played with some values and get this response from whole loop Vout/Vin. I have added another picture. I would like to have Phase margin 60 degrees, but 50 is probably ok.  Crossover frequency is 6,5 khz. Do you consider this as stable?

Comment: It does seem ok and you should not try a transient load step at different input voltages and see if the response is acceptable or not.

Comment: Just curious how is compensation done if i want variable output voltage. If I use potentiometer instead of resistor divider  i will have variable impedance on the input of error op amp which will result in different body plot.  And if i use op amp as buffer i am awared that op amp will fight AC coupled voltage from feedback network.